# Searching API for a specific Json key, value

Tags: api, wunderground

I'm using the wunderground api to get weather conditions from a specific city. They have various ways to query the data here ---> http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/index. The response is in JSON.

Is there a possible way to GET the locations from a specific key, value using the api; like getting all the cities that have a current temperature of 75 degrees, without getting the data for various locations, then checking if the temperature is a certain number?

Comment: That's a very weird requirement and I'm pretty sure that this weather API doesn't support it. But, you may go ahead and read the documentation and see if there's such an option.

Comment: There isn't any functionality like that in the API or on wunderground.com. Its a data concept we talk about, but there's no plans to make this feature a reality any time soon.